# How to unescape and parse nested JSON array of object?

Tags: javascript, json

I am supposed to unescape an parse this kind of json array of objects

```
 {
    "httpAlertId": 14,
    "httpAlertName": "raja67",
    "httpUrl": "http://example.com",
    "httpRequestType": "GET",
    "httpHeaders": "sadasdsad",
    "httpVarMap": "{\"Sdsd\":\"dss\"}",
    "httpTimeout": 99,
    "httpRetries": 1,
    "httpCredentials": "{\"username\":\"somename\",\"password\":\"something\"}",
    "mappedAlertActionConfigId": 0
}
```

What I am expecting is the value of `httpCrenentials` must become normal JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = {
    "httpAlertId": 14,
    "httpAlertName": "raja67",
    "httpUrl": "http://example.com",
    "httpRequestType": "GET",
    "httpHeaders": "sadasdsad",
    "httpVarMap": "{\"Sdsd\":\"dss\"}",
    "httpTimeout": 99,
    "httpRetries": 1,
    "httpCredentials": "{\"username\":\"somename\",\"password\":\"something\"}",
    "mappedAlertActionConfigId": 0
}

var nJSON = {};
for(key in a){
  var val;
  try{
    nJSON[key] = JSON.parse(a[key]);
  }catch(e){
    nJSON[key] = a[key];
  }
}

console.log(nJSON);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Lets say i have array of similar objects, Whats the optimized way to do this for each object?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, I have Interpreted it in wrong. Thanks for pointing.